# C4800 error, compiling with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013 compiler is giving me warning C4800:

```
'UInt32' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' for the following code. (evn->unk08 is a void* array)
```

Why is that? I have added extra brackets for safety. The same error occurs for != operator. Is there a better way to do this?

```
if ((((UInt32)(evn->unk08[2]) & 8)) == 0)
```

Comment: Are you sure that is your actual code, and the warning concerns that line? Did you perchance write `&&` instead of `&` in your actual code?

Comment: 100% certain. I'm checking for the flag there.

Comment: For safety on 64bit platforms, you should use uintptr_t. Also, try extracting the cast in a different variable and give it another go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (and imo should) try to extract part of the expression into some variables and see if (and where) the problem still occurs, e.g.

```
UInt32 something = reinterpret_cast<UInt32>(evn->unk08[2]);
bool isSomeFlagSet = (something & 8) == 0;
if (isSomeFlagSet) { /* ... */ }
```

This does, apart from avoiding getting lost in all those parens, serve readability and also makes it easier to debug the values of all the parts of the expression, because they are stored in variables with (hopefully meaningful) names.

Comment: Most of your answer is about variable names, which are not related to the problem in the question, or the C-style cast, which is not related either. The questioner is not asking for a code review. Maybe you can refocus this post?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I grant you, it got a bit out of hand - but the lack of variables and squeezing everything into one single line probably *is* the root cause of problem. I'll edit the post